# Use java.io.File on Android

Tags: java, android

Unfortunately, i need to deal with `java.io.File` because i use `jgit` and the API use this class.

I need to ask the user a directory on the shared storage. For that i used `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

This return me this URI: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FRepo`

Repo is a directory which exist in Download/Repo/.

Then i tried different things like using `java.nio.file.FileSystem`: `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(localPath.value).toFile()`
The path will be equal to `content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FRepo`
*there is one '/' this time*

and `File(URI(localPath.value))`

But in both cases, `file.exists()` return false.

Comment: Of course. A content scheme (two slashes) is no file path and hence cannot be used with the File class.

Comment: Is there a simple way of retrieving a path in Android or do I have to implement a file manager in my app?

Comment: You can use the File class to list() all public directories on external storage. Then let the user choose one.

Comment: what method exactly? using `File.listRoots()` doesn't seems to works

Comment: `val file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` made it, thanks